# Segue back button disappeared in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, back-button

Before iOS 9 was released, I've developed an app targeting iOS 8.4. I've used some `UITableView` connected each other via segue of kind "Show (e.g. Push)". It worked perfectly with the right behavior: every time I switched from a `UITableView` to another, the back button appeared, so the user is able to turn back to the previous scene; the back button appeared also from `UITableView` to `UIViewController`, using the same kind of segue. 
Now I have upgraded to the latest version of Xcode and targeting the app to iOS 9.0, I got this problem: now, if I go from `UITableView` to another `UITableView`, the back button doesn't appear anymore, but if I go from `UITableView` to `UIViewController`, the back button appears. I've seen other developers has had a similar problem (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675414/ios9-navigation-bar-back-button-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687549/doesnt-show-the-back-button-in-navigation-bar-in-ios-9) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692269/uinavigationbar-back-button-disappears)), but I don't understand how they have solved (except for the third link, but it's not my case). Anyone knows how can I get back button working again? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: can you provide screenshots ? are you changing anything in NavigationBarItem ?

Comment: you can embed the parent view controller in Navigation controller

Comment: @ogres I've edited my post, you can see a screenshot of my storyboard. The only change in NavigationBarItem is the title of the NavigationBar and the title of the back button

Comment: @engmahsa I don't understand, can you provide me an example or explanation?

Comment: try directly opening Menu Locale NC-s rootViewcontroller and not the Navigationcontroller, because when you are pushing navigation onto navigation maybe its confusing?

Comment: Got it, I wonder why Apple guys didn't decided to keep it working anyway for the older apps. By the way, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the guy who posted the second link is having the same problem as you. In a comment he said that the way he fixed it was getting rid of the extra navigation controllers:

> No need put the navigation controller for each view. put the navigation controller start view only.

So that is what I would suggest doing. Only put a navigation controller on the first view controller. Get rid of all the others.

Comment: Yes, right, I had read the solution of the second link, but I didn't understand how to do it. So, thank you, but special thanks to @ogres too!

Answer (score 2):

So, thanks to Caleb's and ogres' suggestions, I solved my problem in this way as you can see in this screenshot, I hope it helps anyone who will have the same problem!

[image]

If you have two `UITableViews` and you want connect them to each other, you just need one `NavigationController`.